# Automatic Endpoint Description for HttpApplication

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

I have a HttpApplication (C#/VS2010/.Net 4.0/MVC4) and i want to genereate a help page with all endpoints and the according comments. There is something similar for in WCF (webHttpBinding, helpEnabled="true").
If there is something, i google the wrong magic words.

Any Idea?

Thx in advance!

Dexit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was lokking for:

Source:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592139/is-it-possible-to-obtain-class-summary-at-runtime)

Solution => [Jolt.NET](http://jolt.codeplex.com)  & [BFree's Suggestion](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49)